# HTML5 Canvas & z-index issue in Google Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, html5-canvas, z-index

I have found that applying a z-index to a canvas that has `position:fixed` causes Chrome to stop rendering all other elements which have `position:fixed` properly. However, this only happens if the canvas is greater than 256x256px in size.

Here's an example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    h1     { position: fixed; }
    body   { height: 2000px; }
    canvas { position: fixed; z-index: -10; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Test Title</h1>
  <canvas id="backgroundCanvas" width="956" height="256"></canvas>
  <script>
  // draw basic shape
  (function() {
    var c = document.getElementById("backgroundCanvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(0,100);
    ctx.lineTo(0,0);
    ctx.lineTo(100,0);
    ctx.lineTo(1000,1000);
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(117, 164, 68)";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
  })();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

If you paste this into a html document and open it in Chrome, you should see what I mean.

My question is, does anyone know of a way I can get around this issue?

Comment: Hi! I tested this code in [jsfidle](http://jsfiddle.net/roimergarcia/gmvL7/) and looks OK for me in Chrome 23/Linux: I can see a canvas with a five sides green shape drawn on it and a title (h1) element overlapping it. What do you see in your computer?

Comment: I see the same. However, if I try scrolling down then the title disappears upwards, despite being `position:fixed;`. It is only rendered in the right place when I resize the browser.

Comment: I am using Chrome V23.0.1271.64 and Windows 7

Comment: It is weird, it doesn't happen in my computer: when I scroll both the canvas and the title remain fixed on screen. Try inspecting the html with chrome and see if the title is really getting the css rule for it. Also try fixing a different element (a div, a span...) and see if the behavior id the same. Also try scrolling horizontally.

Comment: When I inspect element, it highlights the area where it's supposed to be, but it just isn't rendered there. It has all the CSS it's supposed to have and it works fine in other browsers (even IE9!) It seems to happen for any kind of fixed element. I'm stumped!

Comment: It's weird as I use a full screen fixed canvas with index -1 on my landing page and there is no problem with the other elements (not many, but they render) (to see: http://abdiassoftware.com/ ).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tested the same fiddle in Chrome 27/winXP and it behaves exactly as you describe; It looks like a bug in chrome or webkit for windows, I tested early with chrome 23/linux and it worked OK.

I found a workarround  [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gmvL7/3/) by warping both, the h1 and the canvas with a fixed div:

```
<div id='fixedContainter'>
    <h1>Test Title</h1>
    <canvas id="backgroundCanvas" width="956" height="256"></canvas>
</div>
```

The div should also have z-index:-10 if your intent is to make it a *background*.

CSS:

```
#fixedContainter{position: fixed; z-index: -10; }
h1{position: fixed;}
body{height: 2000px; }
canvas{ position: fixed; z-index: -10; }
```

​

Comment: That will require I keep all of my fixed position elements in the same container element, but thankfully that works out for this application. Good work!

Comment: You are welcome :) ... There is something else: in chrome/windows I can't see the vertical scroll bar, but in chrome/Linux I can; I'm sure it isn't a feature but a bug in chrome or webkit.

Answer (score 0):

I had that problem in Chrome on Win8, and making canvas and siblings position:fixed did't help me. I found that i had negative z-index on canvas DIV. When I rearrange my code and make that z-index positive, canvas stopped flickering my overlay DIVs

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with negative z-indexes, and a simple fix if you can allow for it is to set the html elements overflow-y to auto.

```
html{
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
* {
z-index: inherit;
}
```

works for me.