# Can't draw on canvas of a certain size

Tags: html, google-chrome, canvas

For some reason, if the second canvas in the following code has a height of more than 526 pixels, nothing will draw to it in Chrome. It works fine as long as height < 527, and always works in Firefox. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I'm very new to HTML, so sorry if I've missed something.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
 <script type="text/javascript">

function init()
{
    var canv = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = canv.getContext("2d");
    ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canv.width, canv.height);
}

</script>
<style type="text/css">
canvas {border: 1px solid black; }
</style>
</head>
<body onload="init()">
<canvas id="mainFrame" width="700" height="700"></canvas>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="125" height="527"></canvas> <!-- cannot exceed
526 ... WHY? -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What happens if you reduce the height of the first canvas and set a height > 526px on the second? I haven't heard of any pixel restrictions yet, perhaps it's due to the fact you are painting outside of your viewport and thus parts are not painted/nothing's painted at all.

Comment: Changing the height of the first canvas doesn't seem to help, but removing it altogether does fix the issue

Comment: I noticed that adding : #myCanvas{} in your CSS fixes your problem. But of course isn't a good solution..

Comment: interesting ... don't know why, but this certainly helps! Thanks!

Comment: I found a post with almost the same problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13857518/html5-canvas-z-index-issue-in-google-chrome

It looks like a bug in chrome or webkit for windows.

Comment: I tried to reproduce the behavior here [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/roimergarcia/8eXrb/) but whatever I try it paints the second canvas in red as expected. I'm using **Google Chrome 23.0.1271.97 m/Windows XP SP3**

Comment: I tried your jsfiddle but on Chrome 23.0.1271.97 m on Windows 7 x64 I'll get a blank second canvas, reducing height a lower value fixed it. I [forked the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Moonbird_IT/9adpW/), switched to using JQuery's ready() event et voilà it works.

Comment: I've simplified the fiddles (actually I started one from scratch before reading the comments). [Does this work for you?](http://jsfiddle.net/Alpha/37cvt/1/) (always painting it for me)

Answer (score 1):

I tried this on my chrome v.24.0.1312 on win7 x64 and it works as is, try updating to the latest version of the browser.